# Difference in results between plt.plot(x,y) and plt.plot(y)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying following code segment:

```
x = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
y = sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x,x)
plt.show()
```

[image: Case 1]
versus

```
plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

[image: Case 2]
In case 1 I get x-limit from 0 to 10 which is expected. However, in second case I get range from 0 to 100 which I am unable to fathom. Can someone please help.
Same behavior can also be shown in a single graph:

```
plt.plot(x,x)
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

[image: Case 3]

In all the cases above x and y remain the same. (Apologies for stating the obvious).
This being my first question here I apologize if I have done something wrong.

I tried different plot types it has very similar behavior unable to understand the underlying rationale for the same.

Comment: Simply because you got to have an 'x' value to plot against, and if you don't provide any it uses [0,1,2,...] by default, as mentioned in the docs...

Comment: Thank You Julien, so if I understand correctly if x value is not provided it will take x value from x = 0 to x = number of variables in y variable? Because there are 100 y variables it assumes ordinal data from 0 to 100 for each y value?
Thank you so much !!!!

Answer (score 0):

your plots can be understood if you look at the [reference for the plot function](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) and its call signature.

```py
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(*args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs)
plot([x], y, [fmt], *, data=None, **kwargs)
plot([x], y, [fmt], [x2], y2, [fmt2], ..., **kwargs)
```

In particular you can read the parameters descritpion which describes the default values.

```
x, yarray-like or scalar
The horizontal / vertical coordinates of the data points. x values are optional and default to range(len(y)).
```

So `plot(x)` defaults to plot the following points (0, x[0]), (1, x[1](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot)), ..., (len(x), x[len(x)]) while plot(x,y) plots the points (x[0], y[0]) (x[1](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot), y[1](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot)) and so on.

This explain the numbers that you are seeing in the axis, your array has most likely 100 elements which means the x axis for `plot(x)` ranges from 0 to 100.

Comment: Thank you so much guys edoput and julien. This is resolved.